# Trouble connecting into a sharepoint site - Cannot find type

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am having trouble connecting into a sharepoint site, it is telling me to make sure the containing type is loaded but I have added the type to the top of the code and checked the files exist.

Any idea how to fix this?

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 

    $site = "https://removedurlforsecurityreason"
    $listName = "Show Calendar"
    $user = "user@site.onmicrosoft.com"   
    $pwd =ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force  

    $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($site)
    $credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($user,$pwd)
    $ctx.Credentials = $credentials
```

> Error: New-Object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials]: make sure the assembley containing type is loaded

When I run `[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` it says these are loaded below:

```
True v2.0.50727 C:\Windows|assembly|GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client\14.0.0.0.0_r324324324\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll

True v2.0.50727 C:\Windows|assembly|GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.sSharePoint.Client\14.0.0.0.0_r324324324\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
```

Comment: you need to Download SharePoint Online Management Shell. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588

Comment: Ok thank you, I better check with a senior here that I can do that then as I am using a clients remote system atm!

Comment: You do not need the SPO management Shell... It is a class within Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll. Are you sure it is loading correctly?

Comment: @Bunzab Updated my question to show its loaded in

Comment: Strange that they are in the GAC. They are not the assemblies you are loading in your script...

Comment: Yeah they did look different to what im loading in but have the same file names at the end of the paths >.<

Comment: I have read somewhere else about the SharePoint Online Management Shell fixing this... so downloading now :)

Comment: If they are in the GAC, try removing your two `add-type` commands and replace with `[system.reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")` and `[system.reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")`